# Implementation of glutdisplayFunc()

Tags: opengl

I've used glutdisplayFun(void(*func)) in several of my program to sets the callback display to the current window.And by the use of it, i've rendered different things on the screen. By looking at the documentation of glut, passing null to it is illegal and we can't deregister it also.

The problem is that as we can't deregister it and i write a set of code to display the mainmenu(i.e as shown in the game). And i like to change to next window on the keypress(i.e play the game by clicking on the option play present in the mainmenu).

How to make the glutdisplayfunc call to the mainmenu inactive and and to set the glutdisplayfunc() for calling the next window.

Comment: I think you could just *not* use `glutDisplayFunc` and manage that yourself. It's really not that hard, and GLUT is fit mostly for simple programs, really.

Comment: Can u give me hint about it?? And i've difficult time understanding glutoverlayDisplayfunc() which i think an alternative to it.plz,say something about it

Comment: Actually you know what? Screw this. I'll post you a simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::%something%<std::function<void(void)>> displayFns;

void myDisplayFunc() {
    for (auto& displayFn : displayFns)
        displayFn();
}
```

Now register `myDisplayFunc` to GLUT and change the `displayFns` collection.

As for something, `map<int, function<...>>` would be a good start. Unordered map if you can guarantee your code doesn't need to be called in order. It starts to resemble good old BASIC times with line numbers, but I said upfront it will be a simple answer.

---

That's not how I would do it, but should do the trick for a quick'n'easy solution.

Funny thing with this is that you can create sets of those to have one element appear in more than one choice rather easily. So maybe it's not that bad after all.

Comment: Tx. I got the ur function defination and ur way of doing this. well, as i've been started coding in c++  for 2 months(i used to code in c  mostly and python).i'm not catching up the first line but i'll try it.

Comment: @Abhaya First line was meant as a placeholder for an std container; a `vector`, `set` or `map` (possibly unordered) should be picked basing on your preferred usage.